# private member accessible from other instances of the same class

Tags: oop

I just noticed something that I've never realised before. It turns out that this class is valid in C#:

```
class Foo
{
    private string contents;

    public Foo(string str) {
        contents = str;
    }

    public void set(Foo other)
    {
        contents = other.contents;
    }
}
```

So different instances of the same class can access the private members of each other.

Up til now, I thought that the private members of an object could only be accessed by that object, not by other instances of the same class. It's a little suprising to find this out.

Is this the case in all common object oriented languages? It's not intuitive for me.

Comment: It turns out someone already asked a pretty similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346127/access-private-member-variable-of-the-class-using-its-object-instance?rq=1 . The answers to that one don't give an authoritive reason for this design choice, though. Is it just because doing it differently is inefficient/impossible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the same as in C++ and Java: access control works on per-class basis, not on per-object basis.

In C++, Java and C# access control is implemented as a static, compile-time feature. This way it doesn't give any run time overhead. Only per-class control can be implemented that way.

Comment: Why is this the case?  Can't the compiler just forbid calling a private method on anything other than the (implicit or explicit) `this` reference?  It would mean that private methods can't be called on other variables that happen to refer to `this`, but I don't see any disadvantage of that.  I think japreiss's answer is more correct.

Answer (score 14):

How would you make a copy constructor for a class that does not expose all of its internal state through public methods?

Consider something like this:

```
class Car
{
public:
    void accelerate(double desiredVelocity);
    double velocity() const;
private:
    Engine myEngine;
};
```

The `Car`'s public interface doesn't expose its `Engine`, but you need it to make a copy.

Comment: Yes; this. There would be no other decent way to make copy/clone methods. You could make it protected internal if you were concerned about it somehow being accessed outside the assembly or something.

Comment: It's also necessary for implementing equals().

Answer (score 1):

For the exact same scenario there is 'Object specific Private' in Scala vs 'Class specific Private' which is not supported in Java also.

```
class Foo {

  private[this] def contents // [this] marks the property as private to the owner

  def doFoo(other: Foo) {
    if (other.contents) { // this line won't compile
      // ...
    }
  }

}
```

This came as a 
surprise that such feature is not supported in other modern languages [private[this] vs private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698677/privatethis-vs-private), I understand this may be not a security risk as such considering it's still tied to the Class and you can still access all the private variables with reflection either way for eg [Does reflection breaks the idea of private methods, because private methods can be access outside of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300680/does-reflection-breaks-the-idea-of-private-methods-because-private-methods-can).

If you look at from Python language perspective, they don't even have scope feature as broad as in C#, in the end it is all about code organization, and from language design perspective it's the learning curve a new comer has to go through

Comment: Thank you sooo much for this explanation !!